# Iterate over a collection of anonymous type in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, loops

> I'm OK with both C# and VB.NET

I have a function `GetListOfBook`, that returns LINQ to SQL result that has a collection of objects like the following:

var result = GetListOfBook();

- Book is a Book object that property
  of Title and ISBN,
- Category is a string
- Author is an Author object that has
  Name and ID property.

So inside the collecton, it looks like this:

So inside the "result" collection it looks like this:

```
{Book = {Book}, Category = "English", Author = {Author}}
{Book = {Book}, Category = "English", Author = {Author}}
{Book = {Book}, Category = "Web Development", Author = {Author}}
```

I want to iterate over each item in the collection to get the Book title and ISBN, Category and the author name. Something like this:

```
foreach (var r in result)
{
    Respone.Write(r.Book.Title, r.Book.ISBN, r.Category, r.Auhtor.Name);
}
```

At the moment, I cannot iterate over the collection yet. Thank you for any suggestion.

**Update:**

Sorry for the trouble. This is actually working. I found the typo in the code.

Comment: What is the signature of `GetListOfBook()`?

Comment: It returns type of IQueryable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need to use the correct syntax for `foreach` which requires you to specify a type for the loop variable. Since you can't name it explicitly, you need to use `var` which infers the type.

```
foreach (var r in result)
{
    Respone.Write(r.Book.Title, r.Book.ISBN, r.Category, r.Auhtor.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an *implicitly typed variable* using [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) for the iteration variable within `foreach`, just as you presumably have for your query to start with:

```
var result = ...; // Your existing query

// r is implicitly typed here
foreach (var r in result)
{
    Response.Write(r.Book.Title, r.Book.ISBN, r.Category, r.Author.Name);
}
```

EDIT: Looking more closely at your code, I suspect this is the problem:

```
var result = GetListOfBook();
```

This can't be strongly typed, if it's returning an anonymous type... which means it must be returning something like `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<object>`. I suspect you'll need to create an appropriate "normal" type to contain the results from `GetListOfBook` - or perform the query in the same method that does the `Response.Write` call.

Comment: You have any idea to make VS show intellisense. Because there's no intellisense for r in this case.

Comment: @Narazana: That suggests your query isn't strongly typed. Will update.

Comment: No it's not a strongly typed.

Comment: @Narazana: Then you're not going to be able to access it statically, are you? See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

you can use reflection like this:

```
foreach (var r in result)
{
    PropertyInfo info = r.GetProperty("Category");
    Response.Write(info.GetValue(r, null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to access the anonymous type's properties.
You can see some samples here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/10/26/c-3-0-anonymous-type-and-net-reflection-hand-in-hand.aspx

But you should do it really as a last resort if you MUST use anonymous types rather than explicit types.

Comment: why go with reflection? instead his only requirement is iterating over Collection, which can be simply achieved by loop and var as return type..

Comment: He can't access the properties of an anonymous type if the object in an Object collection.